# Jquery .clone() method. Removing clones

Tags: javascript, jquery

I noticed some interesting behavior when dealing with the .clone() function.

If I have a function to create rows and columns dynamically like this:

```
function appendDiv(n) {
    for (var i=0;i<n;i++) {
        $rows.append($columns.clone()); //assume I put $('.rows') & others in a var
    }
    for (var i=0;i<n;i++) {
        $wrapper.append($rows.clone());
    }
}
```

And I then delete the elements from the DOM maybe like this:

```
    function deleteClones() {
    $wrapper.off();
    $wrapper.html('');
    $('body').append($wrapper);
    num = prompt("Enter another number.");
    return num;
}
```

So I'd be calling the functions in an order like this:

```
appendDiv(num);
num = deleteClones();
appendDiv(num);
```

Can someone tell me why when I call `appendDiv(num);` again after removing those elements, the old columns are added along with the new ones? Here is a preschool level demonstration of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/wj6sgeeu/. Notice upon inspecting the html document, the clones that were created before we called `deleteClones()` are added again when we call `appendDiv(num)` for the second time.

I'm new to jquery, so maybe this is a self evident and obvious fact (maybe using a different method to remove clones?) but does someone have an explanation for this behavior?

Thank you!

Comment: What is `$wrapper` in `deleteClones()`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot access your demo.

Comment: @PeterKA - the jsFiddle is written in a way that you can't see the code until you answer the first two prompts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the previously added columns from the row, else you are just keep adding more columns to the existing columns

```
function appendDiv(n) {
    $rows.empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        $rows.append($columns.clone());
        console.log('ok');
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        $wrapper.append($rows.clone());
        console.log('ok2');
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nj5gx7m8/)

Comment: Ok, I was under the assumption that my deleteClones() function would delete the children of wrapper and all it's descendants. Great answer, solved. Thanks